# how can I use facebook sdk swift 4.1 branch for ios

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, branch, podfile

I need to Use FaceBook Sdk Swift 4.1 Branch

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', :git => 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk.git' :branch => 'swift-4.1'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', :git => 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk.git'  :branch => 'swift-4.1'
pod 'FacebookShare', :git => 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk.git' :branch => 'swift-4.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a missing ***,*** before :branch
it should be this

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', :git => 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk.git', :branch => 'swift-4.1'

pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', :git => 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk.git',  :branch => 'swift-4.1'

pod 'FacebookShare', :git => 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk.git', :branch => 'swift-4.1'